# appcfg download_data on downloading blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

In AppEngine i could download the data from appspot to my local using appcfg download_data but it seems to be now downloading the one from the blobstore Api, is there any way i could download the blob as well as the data keeping their keys synchronized?

So the final outcome is I download data from the server (including blob) go to another pc and upload all data and blob thus when i run it, it would look like the one the appspot. Thanks